# Are join clauses the only method to realize this and CTEs cannot?

Tags: mysql, join, common-table-expression, outer-join

Here is my table(created at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5dKasZPNK7SqjnXvsj7qqX/54)) and I want to find one person(anyone) that triggered an event name and retrieve all the records of that user on that day.

| user_id | date_time | event_name | trivial | trivial_new |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2020-12-10 10:00:00 | a | 1 | 13 |
| 001 | 2020-12-10 10:00:01 | b | 9 | 19 |
| 001 | 2020-12-10 10:00:02 | c | 3 | 21 |
| 001 | 2020-12-10 10:00:20 | d | 6 | 20 |
| 001 | 2020-12-10 10:00:40 | e | 2 | 11 |
| 002 | 2020-12-09 10:00:02 | A | 2 | 15 |
| 002 | 2020-12-10 10:00:09 | B | 4 | 15 |
| 002 | 2020-12-10 10:00:10 | C | 9 | 15 |
| 002 | 2020-12-10 10:00:50 | D | 0 | 13 |

I learned the CTEs from [What is a Common Table Expression?](https://www.percona.com/blog/2020/02/10/introduction-to-mysql-8-0-common-table-expressions-part-1/) and in that article, I learned that:

> We can define a CTE as an alternative to a derived table. In a small way, CTE simplifies complex joins and subqueries, improving the readability of the queries.

And here is [my attempt](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5dKasZPNK7SqjnXvsj7qqX/54) using CTE:

```
WITH temp AS
(
       SELECT user_id,
              date_time
       FROM   log_table
       WHERE  binary event_name = "B" limit 1 )
SELECT   *
FROM     log_table
WHERE    user_id = temp.user_id
AND      substring_index(date_time, ' ', 1) = substring_index(temp.date_time, ' ', 1)
ORDER BY date_time
```

It triggered an error that reads that:

> Query Error: Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'temp.user_id'
> in 'where clause'

I was told that the only method is using join, and then I tried that as follows:

```
SELECT t_left.*
FROM   log_table AS t_left
       RIGHT JOIN (SELECT user_id,
                          date_time
                   FROM   log_table
                   WHERE  BINARY event_name = 'B'
                   LIMIT  1) AS t_right
               ON t_left.user_id = t_right.user_id
                  AND Substring_index(t_left.date_time, ' ', 1) =
                      Substring_index(t_right.date_time, ' ', 1)
ORDER  BY date_time
```

I wonder if I can realize that using CTEs since *CTE simplifies complex joins*?

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. What is yours? PS `from log_table` doesn't use temp. You define temp, but you don't join with it. PS We should be able to cut & paste & run a [mre] from text in your post. That includes initial table values given via code. But it should also be formatted in columns. (And using a html table on such code would just add a lot of useless horizontal space.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have to add the CTE to a JOIN.

This would be the correct way to write your query:

```
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT user_id, date_time
  FROM log_table
  WHERE binary event_name = "B"
  LIMIT 1
)
SELECT l.*
FROM log_table l
JOIN temp ON l.user_id = temp.user_id
    AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(l.date_time, ' ', 1)  = SUBSTRING_INDEX(temp.date_time, ' ', 1)
ORDER BY l.date_time
```

->

```
| user_id | date_time           | event_name | trivial |
| ------- | ------------------- | ---------- | ------- |
| 002     | 2020-12-10 10:00:02 | A          | 2       |
| 002     | 2020-12-10 10:00:09 | B          | 4       |
| 002     | 2020-12-10 10:00:10 | C          | 9       |
| 002     | 2020-12-10 10:00:50 | D          | 0       |
```